# crear usuario pero que se pueda identificar como otro

Tags: linux, ssh

tengo un `usuario1` creado con Linux sin bash, ni Home y que no puede iniciar sesión, hecho de la siguiente forma:

```
sudo adduser usuario1
```

Una vez creado, yendo al fichero:

```
sudo nano /etc/passwd
```

he buscado la línea de dicho usuario y he cambiado su Shell por false:

```
usuario1:x:1000:1000 .../home/usuario1:/bin/false
```

Pero ahora necesito crear un `usuario2` que se pueda identificar como el usuario 1 (usando sudo) pero no como root.

¿Cómo podría hacer eso?

Muchas gracias. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @ProgrammerJr , yo creo que tengo idea, estoy siguiendo un curso de servidores Linux y hice algo parecido hace poco, pero no se explicarme. En stack hay otro sitio dedicado a Ubuntu, ASK ubuntu. Quiza ya conoccas, si no este es le enlace [https://askubuntu.com/](https://askubuntu.com/) Espero encuentres solucion. Suerte